# Angular 2 how to redirect after REST http post/put as per the returned Status code

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-http

I'm trying to redirect/ reroute it to a specific page after success and failure of my http put request. the API returns some status codes as per the success or error (500, 401, 200 etc)
I dont know how to handle this redirection

my service code is as shown below

```
putCustomer(body: string){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method: 'put', withCredentials: true });

    return this.http.put(this._customerUrl, body, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError)
        .subscribe();
}
private handleError (error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || ' error');
}
```

Please help.

UPDATE:
some minor adjustments to Fredrik's Answer:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

.........

constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http) { }

      putCustomer(body: string){
            let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method: 'put', withCredentials: true });

            //alert(body);
            return this.http
            .put(this._customerUrl, body, options)
            .do(res => {
            if(res.status === 200 ||res.status === 201) {
              this.router.navigate(['/success']);
            }
            else if(res.status === 401){
              this.router.navigate(['/error']);
            }
            else if(res.status >= 500){
              this.router.navigate(['/error']);
            }
          })
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError)
            .subscribe();
        }
        private handleError (error: Response) {
            console.error(error);
            return Observable.throw(error.json().error || ' error');
        }

    }
```

Comment: Remove the handleError method and the call to catch, remove the call to map(), and add two subscribe callbacks that inspect the response status and act accordingly. You're interested in the response status, but both your map and your catch callbacks remove this information, by transforming the response to something else that you're not interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Response.status` to get the status code from the http response. Then use the `Router.navigate(...)` to redirect. You can use the `do` operator on the *Observable* to perform the *side effect* of navigating to another route.

**Snippet:**

```
.do(res => {
   if(res.status === '200') this.router.navigate(['/somewhere']);
   else if(......) ...;
 })
```

**More full example to integrate with your code:**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

...

export class YourClass {

  constructor(router: Router, ...) {}

  putCustomer(body: string){

    ...

    return this.http
      .put(this._customerUrl, body, options)
      .do(res => {
        if(res.status === '200') this.router.navigate(['/somewhere']);
        else if(......) ...;
      })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError)
      .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Fredrik... I think this should work... will give it a shot and update.

Answer (score 0):

Just import the router

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

then have it injected into the constructor:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

then use the router to do the redirection

```
this.router.navigate(['/nextPage']);
```